# join 2 RDDs using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have two `RDDs`

The first one `(productID,category)`

The second one `(customerID,productID,quantity)`

How can I make output looks like `(customerID,category,quantity)`?

The logic is to replace each `productID` of second `rdd` with corresponding `category` of first `rdd`.

I would like to use scala for the solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have two `case classes` for your two `rdds`

```
case class Products(productId:String, category:String)
case class Customer(customerId:String, productId:String, quantity:Int)
```

You have two `rdds` as

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Products("product1", "category1"),
  Products("product2", "category2"),
  Products("product3", "category3"),
  Products("product4", "category4")
))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Customer("customer1", "product1", 5),
  Customer("customer1", "product2", 6),
  Customer("customer2", "product3", 2),
  Customer("customer2", "product4", 9)
))
```

You can simply `join` the two `rdds` with productId but before joining them you will have to created `pairRDD` with productId as key.

```
rdd1.map(prod => (prod.productId, prod))
rdd2.map(customer => (customer.productId, customer))
```

Final step is a simple `join` and select the values you want.

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).map(x => (x._2._2.customerId, x._2._1.category, x._2._2.quantity))
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you...
But here `customer` and `products` are  one value in a pair 
I can't access values of classes in this way or with `mapValues(x=>x(0),....)`

Comment: `customer` and `products` are not as one value. They are `Tuple2`. If they were combined as an `array` then you can do `x(0)` but they are in `Tuples` so correct way to get values is by using `_1 .....` You can convert the `tuples` to `array` but that would be extra work. You can ask for more if its still not clear. :)